# How to integrate Stripe Payment in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I need a Stripe Implementation for my Java Android App, but with a Server in Java, I don't know how to use node or php to implement that server-side and I found something on their docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=elements#android-create-payment-intent

but, the server-side is poorly explained.

All I've wrote until now is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="30dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Checkout">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"

     >

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:src="@drawable/logo"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/youhavetopay"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
         android:fontFamily="@font/muli_black"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         />
     <com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
         android:id="@+id/cardInputWidget"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />


     <Button

         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/payButton"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         />
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and this

```
public class Checkout extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button payBtn;
    String message;
    String price;
    TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);

        payBtn = findViewById(R.id.payButton);
        text = findViewById(R.id.youhavetopay);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
            message = extras.getString("message");
            price = extras.getString("passprice");
        }
        String t = "Pay $"+price;
        payBtn.setText(t);
        text.setText(message);




    }
}
```

I have these implementations :

```
    implementation "com.stripe:stripe-java:15.1.0"
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

I really don't understand what I have to do from their docs. I only want a pay button that makes a payment from that card and if its accepted, do something on the database. A simple payment.

If you can guide me please, I would appreciate it! Any tutorials or advices are welcomed. I've tried to copy from the GitHub, but I saw many red lines from imports and I got lost.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample includes both example [Android client](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/tree/master/without-webhooks/client/android) and a [Java server](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/tree/master/without-webhooks/server/java) implementations. You should be able to clone the repository and follow the appropriate READMEs to run those examples and see how this works. Follow along with the guide and if you have more specific questions please raise those.

You will need to be able to install and build android & java to run this, of course.